# How to access third party API data in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

I would like to ask how can I access the fields in json ("latitude", "latitude") to be able to display them as string in the browser.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class ISSTrackerController {

    @GetMapping("/location")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getISSLocation() {
        String uri = "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a `String`, `result` should be a class that represents the returned JSON structure of invoking that endpoint (or an app specific DTO to avoid the endpoint response from leaking).  Also, `RestTemplate` is thread safe and injectable, so should not need to create a new instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data from the response in java, you will need to create some POJOs to get the response:

```java
class IssPosition {
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    // getters & setters
}

class IssResponse {
    // Here the iss_position property in hte response is in cammel case,
    // with the @JsonProperty annotation we tell the parser to pass that 
    // property to the annotated field issPosition
    @JsonProperty("iss_position")
    private IssPosition issPosition;
    private String message;
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Then you can make your call with `RestTemplate`

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class ISSTrackerController {

    @GetMapping("/location")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getISSLocation() {
        String uri = "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<IssResponse> response = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, IssResponse.class);
        // We get te response as an IssResponse object
        IssResponse result = response.getBody();
        // We get the iss_position property so you have access 
        // to the latitude and longitude fields by
        IssPosition position = result.getIssPosition();
        // You can just return the position so you have a json like this one: 
        // { "latitude": "-24.0470", "longitude": "64.0261" }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(position, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

PS:
Edited the answer to use the actual response wrapped in `ResponseEntity` from the RestTemplate call.
Thanks to @OneCricketeer for pointing that out!!!

Comment: Did you want `ResponseEntity<IssPosition>` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Only in the method type should be <IssPosition> instead of <String>, but I dealt with that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/location")
private String getISSLocation()
{
    String url = "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
    return result;
}
```